# run for each loop in parallel

Tags: unix, ksh

if I have a for each statement like this:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
    fairly large script here with lots of logic and stuff and $i is in many areas..the code in ehre also needs to run in a sequence...
done
```

how can I spawn the 4 loops in parallel and not run in serial

Comment: By using my answer... -_-

Comment: Take a look at the "parallel" command (https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you mean now. You want 4 pairs of jobs to run in parallel and the 2 halves of each pair need to run sequentially. So, in essence, you have

```
Job 1A followed sequentially by Job 1B
Job 2A followed seuqentially by Job 2B
Job 3A followed sequentially by Job 3B
Job 4A followed sequentially by Job 4B
```

and the 4 lines above can all be run in parallel.

If that is the case, you need:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 ; do 
   ( echo $i A start; sleep 5; echo $i A end; echo $i B start; sleep 5; echo $i B end ) &  
done
```

Comment: so would I have to do a start for every command inside the loop then? I have about 700 lines of code inside the loop with various variables, other loops and condition statements. Would I do a start at the end of each one of those? I'm still confused on where the start and end go i guess...

Comment: Put your 700 lines of code in a separate script, and just call the script from inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

With the `&` operator (run in background)

```
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
    echo "test 1 $i" &
    echo "test 2 $i" &
done
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that you can add `wait` on the line after `done` if you want to wait till all 8 processes finish.

Comment: maybe I should have been a little bit more clear with my question...so I want so i is going to run for 1, 2, 3 and 4. But I don't want i to run for 1 then 2 then 3 et...I want i to run 1,2,3 and 4 at teh same time.

Comment: @user2061886 Did you even try what sputnick suggested? It runs all 8 processes at the same time in parallel. Try replacing the `echo` command with `sleep 5; echo done` and you will see it takes 5 seconds not 40.

Comment: I understand what he is saying, but I think my question wasn't asked correctly. The stuff inside the loop needs to run in a sequence. Not sure if it would work that way if the stuff inside the loop needs to run in a sequence?...I updated my question too..hopefully it make more sense...